# Why does ImmutableList cause recomposition in Jetpack Compose?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

In [this article](https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/jetpack-compose-stability-explained-79c10db270c8), it says that if the argument type of a composable is `ImmutableList`, it is considered as stable, meaning that if the list didn't change, the composable won't be recomposed.

```
@Immutable
data class Contact(val name: String, val age: Int)


@Composable
fun ContactRow(contacts: ImmutableList<Contact>, modifier: Modifier = Modifier) {
  var selected by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }
  Row(modifier) {
    ContactDetails(contacts)
    Checkbox(selected, onCheckedChange = {
      selected = !selected
    })
  }
}

@Composable
fun ContactDetails(contacts: ImmutableList<Contact>) {
  Text(text = contacts[0].name)
}
```

Here, every time I select the checkbox, the `ContactDetails` composable is recomposed, even though I am using `ImmutableList` from KotlinX collections.

My compose version is also 1.2.0

[image: My Compiler reports also mark this as unstable]

Comment: any update on this? i have the same problem with kotlin 1.7.20 and compose 1.3

Comment: How can I open that main-debug window thing?

Answer (score 1):

There has to be a small mistake on your side.
Code presented here is valid, ContactDetails will be [skipped](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/mental-model#skips), not recomposed. Compiler marks both ContactRow and ContactDetails as stable & skippable.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hey Denis, where do you see these information?

Comment: @HocineB compose compiler reports. Take a look here https://github.com/androidx/androidx/blob/androidx-main/compose/compiler/design/compiler-metrics.md

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue also until I updated my compose and Kotlin version https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/setup.

After which my data class with a ImmutableList in became stable. So prehaps you need to update to newer versions too?